# irb does not work after rbenv install

Tags: ruby, environment, rbenv

So I just ditched rvm in order to try rbenv. I installed with macports and followed the instructions regarding installation. However when I try to run irb I get:

```
/Users/user/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-rc1/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/init.rb:236:in `load':
/Users/user/.irbrc:1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...require 'irb/completion'require 'irb/completion'require 'irb...
```

Any one out there run into the same problem or know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend renaming the /Users/user/.irbrc file to some other name, such as irbrc_backup. It obviously contains some invalid code. It will be recreated when you run irb again.

You could compare the newly created one with the one that you renamed to see what has gone wrong.